# Can we replace the pulse transformer with some other circuit element in this circuit?

Tags: transistors, transformer, power-electronics

Our research group was trying to simulate and analyse this circuit. But it seems that the pulse transformer is creating the problem in the sense that we cannot find its models in Pspice, microcap or any other such softwares. We would be grateful if you could help replace the pulse transformer with some other circuit elements or any possible suggestions.

[image: figure]

Comment: Generally, SPICE has no model for transformers. Instead, you can use two inductors and couple them using a `Kname Inductor1 Inductor2 value_of_K` statement (value_of_K is the coupling coefficient); an ideal transformer has a value of 1.0; SPICE supports only values 0<K<1. I guess this is possible in the Pspice dialect as well.

Comment: There is an equivalent circuit of pulse transformer at the link below  http://gbppr.dyndns.org/mil/radar/gbppr_radar/Pulse_Transformer.pdf in page 4 of this link. Can u please help set these circuit values in this model. As you said I can replace pulse transformer by a transformer which in turn by coupled inductors. But can you please inform how accurate it is as I have to order circuit components after simulation.

Answer (score 1):

I use microcap and you create two inductors (say L1 and L2) then choose "k" from: -

component/analog primitives/passive components/k

You then get this dialogue box: -

[image]

Fill out "L1 L2" and coupling and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Also, in LTspice you would model you transformers as 2 inductors and couple them using a "k statement", here is an article regarding [how to model transformers in LTspice](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/lt-journal/LTMag-V16N3-23-LTspice_Transformers-MikeEngelhardt.pdf) for more information